# Sharing files between a windows 10 and ubuntu PCs

Tags: networking, samba, windows-10, file-sharing

I've got Ubuntu 18.4 and windows 10.

I'm trying to share a folder on a second HDD in my Linux machine. I've successfully shared folders and files from my main HDD with no issues but as soon as I try to share anything from my second HDD windows either doesn't detect anything or asks me for the username and password ( which I've followed some tutorials on how to set those in terminal).

I'd like to refrain from using my main HDD for data storage if possible. Tips on what extra steps may be needed to get the second HDD to share would be appreciated.

****Edit****
I've tried both solutions and both solutions have only worked for a short time. After watching one of my movies the second wouldn't play ( no restart on either PC). I'm not sure what to do as following the steps each time doesn't seem to work a second time. This has become very frustrating...

-Cheers

Comment: hi there! I flagged this as a duplicate, feel free to check out the answer. ubuntu comes with file sharing builtin for two machine (windows 10 and ubuntu) that are running at the same time. however if you were refering to your dual boot the best option is simply to use your windows hard drive as the sharing space. both ubuntu and windows can read and write to NTFS partitions but only ubuntu can read ext4 (the partition type that it is installed to)

Comment: Tried all of those things before. Multiple times... This time it worked for some reason *Shrugs* Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Does the second HDD mount to something like /media/your-user-name/XXX.

If that is the case you need to force the client user to appear as "your-user-name". WHere you do that depends on how you created your shares. If it's through Nautilus then edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one - substituting your real user name:

```
force user = your-user-name
```

If you created the shares directly in smb.conf you need to add that line to the share definition itself.

After editing smb.conf remember to restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: And the problem came back. I tried using Morbius1's method and that did the trick (This time lol). Thanks again everyone!